# Very slow Vagrant SSH port forwarding

Tags: ssh, vagrant, portforwarding

I've installed a new Vagrant box for local development using Puphpet, and while the connection through Vagrant box local IP is very fast, the port-forwarded one is really slow, taking about 3-5 seconds to complete.

This considerably impacts PHPUnit testing, which I'm running through PHPStorm IDE.

I've tried disabling the UseDNS and GSSAPIAuthentication in sshd_config, with no improvements.

Any idea what else can be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you tried editing sshd_config.
The sshd is for the server, try editing the client file (without a 'd').

Set `GSSAPIAuthentication=no` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.
When you want to test this without root-access, cp this file to a local_file and use

```
ssh -F path/to/local_file ....
```